# Configure SuSEfirewall2 in SLES12 SP5 to allow multicast via `sit`

Tags: firewall, sles, tunneling, multicast

I'm experimenting with multicasts in our Intranet, but it seems the Intranet does not support multicast routing.

Anyway, I set up an IP-IP tunnel (`sit1`) between two machines in different subnets, and I send test messages to some address and port.
Things work fine when I stop the firewall (SuSEfirewall2), but packets are blocked via `SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT` when I start the firewall.

Basically I wonder what settings to add to allow passing multicasts via `sit1`, and I also wonder whether `--pkt-type broadcast` (which the firewall uses) also allows *multicast* (in `man iptables-extensions` there are two different words for both, but the manual does not explain the details.

I added my test port to `FW_SERVICES_EXT` and allowed `igmp` via `FW_FORWARD` (unsure whether I need that).
In addition I added my test port to `FW_ALLOW_FW_BROADCAST_EXT`.

What I see is that the port is allowed twice via `input_ext` as `broadcast` (see sub-question above).